# tf.keras.optimizers.Adam.apply_gradients triggers tf.function retracing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I'm getting a memory leak and I believe it to be linked to the following warning:

WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function _BaseOptimizer._update_step_xla at 0x7fa9f8074c20> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

The warning occurs in the following function:

```
        def learn(self):
            for _ in range(self.n_epochs):
                state_arr, additional_info, action_arr, old_prob_arr, values, reward_arr, _, trades_complete, env_states, batches = self.memory.generate_batches() # generate batches
                reward_diff = reward_arr[:-1] + values[1:] * (1 - tf.cast(trades_complete[:-1], dtype=tf.float32)) - values[:-1]
                advantage = tf.concat([tf.cumsum(reward_diff, reverse=True), self.zero_tensor], axis=0)
                with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                    new_probs, new_val = self.cnn_actor_critic([state_arr, additional_info])
                    masked_new_probs = ENVIRONMENT.mass_apply_mask(new_probs.numpy(), env_states)
                    rows = tf.range(tf.shape(masked_new_probs)[0])
                    index_arr = tf.add(tf.cast(action_arr, dtype=tf.int32), self.one_val)
                    gather_indices = tf.stack([rows, index_arr], axis=1)
                    chosen_probs = tf.gather_nd(masked_new_probs, gather_indices)
                    new_log_probs_of_old_actions = tf.negative(tf.math.log(chosen_probs))
                    critic_value = tf.squeeze(new_val, 1) # removes dimensions of size 1 from the tensor
                    values_list = tf.convert_to_tensor(values)
                    returns = tf.add(advantage, values_list)
                    critic_loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE(critic_value, returns)
                    prob_ratio = tf.math.exp(tf.add(new_log_probs_of_old_actions,tf.cast(tf.negative(old_prob_arr), dtype=tf.float32)))
                    weighted_probs = tf.multiply(advantage, prob_ratio)
                    clipped_probs = tf.clip_by_value(prob_ratio, 0.8, 1.2)
                    weighted_clipped_probs = tf.multiply(clipped_probs, advantage)
                    l_clip = tf.math.minimum(weighted_probs, weighted_clipped_probs) # prviously actor_loss
                    entropy_term = tf.negative(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(new_log_probs_of_old_actions, tf.math.log(new_log_probs_of_old_actions))))
                    l_q_extension = tf.add(tf.multiply(self.c1,critic_loss), tf.negative(tf.multiply(self.c2,entropy_term)))
                    l_q = tf.negative(tf.add(l_clip,l_q_extension))
                    actor_critic_cnn_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(l_q)
                cnn_actor_critic_params = self.cnn_actor_critic.trainable_variables
                actor_critic_grads = tape.gradient([actor_critic_cnn_loss, critic_loss], cnn_actor_critic_params, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
                self.cnn_actor_critic.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_critic_grads, cnn_actor_critic_params))
            self.memory.clear_memory()
```

More specifically, the last line: `self.cnn_actor_critic.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_critic_grads, cnn_actor_critic_params))`

When this line is commented, I no longer get the warning.

How do I alter the code to avoid the warning and the associated memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found to resolve this issue was downgrading my Tensorflow version to version 2.10.1.

After doing so, the warning no longer appeared, and the RAM usage stabilized at approximately 21.5 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I guess there is a solution that does not require to change the version. Take the line that applies the gradient update to a distinct method decorated by `tf.function` as follows and call it in the place of the removed line:

```
@tf.function 
def apply_grads(opt, grads, tv): 
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tv))
```